# ways to query template specializations at run-time / avoiding the big switch

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, switch-statement, boilerplate

I have a enum type:

```
enum class MyEnumType { A , B , C };
```

and i want to map these enums to description attributes; i like this approach a lot:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyEnumTypeDescription
{
 inline const char* get() { static_assert("description not implemented for this type"); };
};

template<>
const char* MyEnumTypeDescription<MyEnumType::A>::get() { return "A"; }

template<>
const char* MyEnumTypeDescription<MyEnumType::B>::get() { return "B"; }

....
```

a bit verbose but not *that* bad, right?

Now, the part that is cumbersome is when i want to get a description from a enumerator at run-time, it means i need to create a big-switch function

```
const char* getDescriptionFromEnumerator( MyEnumType t ) 
{
   case MyEnumType::A:
       return MyEnumTypeDescription<MyEnumType::A>::get();
   .....
}
```

is there some metaprogramming (template or macro) magic that would help me avoid all this boilerplate and error-prone coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to map it to an array:

```
enum MyEnumType { A , B , C };
const char *pEnumDescription[] = { "A", "B", "C" };
```

And based on index you can get the type at runtime.

```
const char* getDescriptionFromEnumerator(MyEnumType t) 
{
  return pEnumDescription[t];  // just one statement instead of switch/case
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, but i am concerned about the right place to store this array, should it be in the header, near the declaration of the enumerator type? should be in namespace-enclosed global data? in a separate .cpp file?

Comment: @lurscher, you need to define this array in a `.cpp` file and declare it in `.h` file (preferably very near to the `enum`). You can choose to put in a separate `namespace`.